# How can I find what tab a module is associated with in Dojo?

Tags: module, tabs, dojo, tabcontainer

I have a dijit TabContainer with multiple tabs open in it. On some of those tabs I create a new instance of a module. Is there a way to figure out which tab the module is associated with when it's created?

I thought I had this working using the TabContainer's selectedChildWidget, but I've found that I can start loading a tab and change tabs before it gets to the place in the script where it loads the module, which results in the module being associated with the wrong tab. If at all possible, I would like to keep this contained inside the module, and not rely on something outside the module to tell it which tab it's on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have implemented a similar scenario, the components inside the tabContainer should be selected only when the container is activated..

you can listen for '_transition' events in the Container and initialize the 'new' container from the event. and While initializing the module, you need to pass the new container reference, so that the new modules are placed at the relevant containers.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up getting this working by passing the window.frameElement to the module that's mapping tabs to modules. From there I was able to search through each tab's childNodes to find the framElement and determine which tab it goes with. I'm not sure if this is a better solution, but it appears to be working.